How can a transaction view uncommitted changes made by another transaction in UNCOMMITTED READ
I know this is probably a silly question, It is my first, It seems so fundamental that I can't find the answer anywhere, because it must be so straight forward no one explained it.
I want to thoroughly understand how transactions work and in particular isolation levels and especially UNCOMMITTED READ isolation level and dirty read.
There is some contradictory information, All these links below from official documentation:
I read many online resources, some of these:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16
https://medium.com/inspiredbrilliance/what-are-database-locks-1aff9117c290
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17277_02/html/TransactionGettingStarted/isolation.html#dirtyreads
say something along the lines of:
A dirty read is when one transaction can view data modified by another transaction that has not yet been committed, But how is this possible & what does this exactly mean ?
But this is contradictory, If I see the PostgreSQL documentation here:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-transactions.html
It says:

Transactions are a fundamental concept of all database systems. The
essential point of a transaction is that it bundles multiple steps
into a single, all-or-nothing operation. The intermediate states
between the steps are not visible to other concurrent transactions,
and if some failure occurs that prevents the transaction from
completing, then none of the steps affect the database at all.

And here:

Another important property of transactional databases is closely
related to the notion of atomic updates: when multiple transactions
are running concurrently, each one should not be able to see the
incomplete changes made by others. For example, if one transaction is
busy totalling all the branch balances, it would not do for it to
include the debit from Alice's branch but not the credit to Bob's
branch, nor vice versa. So transactions must be all-or-nothing not
only in terms of their permanent effect on the database, but also in
terms of their visibility as they happen. The updates made so far by
an open transaction are invisible to other transactions until the
transaction completes, whereupon all the updates become visible
simultaneously.

I thought transactions are autonomous & all or nothing, so how can an update statement for example in the middle of a transaction before commit be visible to another ?
After all, two or more transactions may even have their own threads/processes in the case of PostgreSQL, so how can they view data before commitment ?
Does this mean when we run individual DML statements inside a transaction they update the rows before commit and then roll back if failed ?
Does this depend on how the locks ?
Because this is the only way I can think it could work
As far as Dirty reads are concerned,
Is a Dirty read the value in the original row that has been selected by another transaction that may modify it or is it the data inside a transaction that has been updated but not committed yet.
I am not geting something very fundamental about this
For example:
Consider this basic example table:
CREATE TABLE TransactionEg (
    id INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    name VARCHAR,
    x INT,
    y INT,
    CONSTRAINT TransactionEgPk PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

INSERT INTO transactioneg (name, x, y)
VALUES
('Row 1', 5, 11),
('Row 2', 7, 23),
('Row 3', 11, 36);


If transaction 1:
BEGIN;
SELECT * FROM transactioneg T WHERE T.id = 1;
UPDATE transactioneg T SET x = x + 5 WHERE T.id = 1;
COMMIT;

At more or less the same time or just after the SELECT statement in the 1st transaction, transaction 2:
BEGIN;
SELECT * FROM transactioneg T WHERE T.id = 1;
UPDATE transactioneg T SET x = x + 10 WHERE T.id = 1;
COMMIT;

Transaction 1 would update the value of x to 10 from 5,
So does transaction 2 see 10 before Commit ?
Or does it just get 5 as thats the original value before commit and the 5 becomes the dirty read ?
Any advice would be appreciated, although I expect I might get downvoted for this question, I hope not.

It is not contradictory for different products to do different things, and to correctly (differently)  document the things they do.


I thought transactions are autonomous & all or nothing, so how can an update statement for example in the middle of a transaction before commit be visible to another ?

Unfortunately, you are noticing the discrepancy between the ideal goals of a transaction control system, which is to facilitate the full isolation of concurrent transactions from one another, and the practical reality of how mainstream SQL database engines and supporting hardware are generally engineered work, and the facilities the engines need both to perform well enough in normal use, to perform adequately under degraded circumstances, and to be supervised adequately.
The READ UNCOMMITTED isolation level is widely regarded as having no legitimate use in the normal operation of a well-designed database application.
It's used for two reasons. One is when dealing with an adaptation to (or ad-hoc query from) an existing application whose existing design precludes the use of the higher isolation levels for performance reasons, and it is considered more important that the new query run at the highest speed possible and with the least prospect of interference in the progression of other transactions, than that the results from the unisolated transaction be theoretically free of defects.
A programmer with a deep understanding of a particular application may be capable of manually reasoning what defects may occur in the circumstances and how frequently, and accepting them as tolerable for the purpose. This might occur when the data informs regular decisions that are individually low-stakes and can sometimes be wrong.
More often, this mode is (mis-)used excessively by incompetent developers to crudely solve performance problems in database applications (typically problems their own work has created), which could usually be solved differently with modest amounts of ordinary design work and standard competencies.
Another reason for using this isolation mode is when some kind of supervisory action is occurring and that supervisor wishes to completely disapply the isolation offered by the transaction manager (for example, this can be to inspect the progress of other concurrent transactions that are themselves running under stronger isolation guarantees).
To properly get to grips with it all, my advice would be to be prepared for a considerable amount of complexity, as the full details do not reduce to simple answers, and details can differ between brands of SQL engine and between different operating modes which those engines provide.
Most practitioners in this area accept that the situation is not good from the perspective of theory or teaching concerns.

Thanks, I would have thought intuitively, the uncommitted read would refer to the original value that was in the row as opposed to inside the transaction, I need to learn how a database manages threads, and requests the same way I understand how web servers work

No.  An uncommitted read could return an /in-flight change/ to that value - an uncommitted one.

Thanks, I understand this is what happens, but I dont get the why/how, The reason why I find this confusing is because, I imagine usually an application would make a request to the database as a client, I expect in a multi-threaded server each request made to the DB would be made by a seperate server side thread, or virtual thread in the case of Java 21+ with these, I can't fathom how how this would work, I do not fully understand how it works at lower layers of abstraction probably, so Im trying to learn, I want to know how this would happen

@theMyth, the essential issue is that it takes time to progressively apply the changes to stored data which a particular transaction causes. Some changes are small and fast, but changes can also be large in a way that occupies the hardware intensively and is slow to complete. When transactions are "isolated", the changes that one transaction causes to the stored data are not visible to any other transaction until the changes are finally "committed". Until commitment, the changes can also be "rolled back", which means all changes to stored data are reversed, as if they were never made. (1/3)

Whilst transactional changes are underway, the storage can be in a condition of having partly-applied changes - that is, a mixture of changes that have already occurred to the stored data, and stored data which is planned to be changed but has not yet been. By default, the engine stops these partly-applied changes being read by any other transaction. A typical approach is that the engine obstructs the concurrent progression of transactions which concern the same data, allowing only one to proceed whilst others must wait. It does this by applying "locks" to the data. (2/3)

The READ UNCOMMITTED isolation level effectively causes locks to be ignored, and allows a read-only transaction to proceed to read the data in whatever its current condition may be at that moment - including reading stored data that has been partly but not yet fully changed by another transaction that is still causing changes (and may even roll back). As I say, this mode exists largely as a coping mechanism, to allow data to be read under circumstances that would otherwise cause "performance emergencies" - where the engine is unable to cope quickly enough with the total demand imposed. (3/3)

A dirty read would be seeing uncommitted data:
-- transaction one
START TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO tab VALUES ('something');

               -- transaction two
               SELECT * FROM tab;

-- transaction one
COMMIT;

If transaction two sees the uncommitted insert, that would be a dirty read.
Different database management systems implement the SQL standard's isolation levels differently.  The SQL standard defines that dirty reads are “possible” on the READ UNCOMMITTED isolation level, but it does not say that you are guaranteed to get dirty reads. PostgreSQL uses that loophole and “upgrades” you to READ COMMITTED when you request READ UNCOMMITTED.
That's not a problem, because nobody really wants to see dirty data. The database management systems that allow you to see dirty data do so because they are using read locks, and you need READ UNCOMMITTED to avoid taking these read locks. In essence, you are sacrificing consistence for concurrency. In PostgreSQL, readers never block writers and vice versa, to there is no need for dirty reads.

Note that due to the way B-Trees and other indexing systems work, it might not be just a single row that's affected, it might be a duplicated row, a missing row, or a whole duplicated/missing page or other section of the index, so other rows (even those not apparently touched by the transaction) may be affected.

@Charlieface I was just showing an example.

I find it hard to understand how in a multi-threaded environment, how is it possible for a transaction to read uncommitted data from another transaction. Where does the transaction store that data mid-transaction ? Is it in some kind of buffer or memory ? Or is it saved to the DB ?

That depends very much on the database. In PostgreSQL, uncommitted modifications are simply stored in the table like everything else. It is the visibility that changes during commit or rollback.

@theMyth Postgres uses MVCC mostly, so it will use the latest version marked as committed. SQL Server on the other hand generally uses pessimistic locking (unless configured) so it will either give uncommitted results or will block waiting for the locks, depending on isolation level.
